# Adding Key and Values of a dictionary to 2 seperate listboxes without duplicates

Tags: c#, dictionary, key-value

I am a beginner programmer and I am creating a match column A with column B using  Windows Forms C# and I need to use a dictionary. I want to display 3 of the keys from the dictionary to a Listbox and 7 values from the dictionary to another Listbox(3 values must pair with the key and the other 4 values must be random). How would I go about doing this. This is the code I have done so far.

```
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        Dictionary<string, string> callingNumbers = new Dictionary<string, string>();

        callingNumbers.Add("000", "Computer science, information & general works");
        callingNumbers.Add("100", "Philosophy & psychology");
        callingNumbers.Add("200", "Religion");
        callingNumbers.Add("300", "Social sciences");
        callingNumbers.Add("400", "Language");
        callingNumbers.Add("500", "Science");
        callingNumbers.Add("600", "Technology");
        callingNumbers.Add("700", "Arts & recreation");
        callingNumbers.Add("800", "Literature");
        callingNumbers.Add("900", "History & geography");




  for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i)
        {
            int index = random.Next(callingNumbers.Count);

            KeyValuePair<string, string> pair = callingNumbers.ElementAt(index);
      
            Console.WriteLine("key: " + pair.Key + ", value: " + pair.Value);
        }


    }
```

Comment: You may find the [Random Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.random?view=net-5.0) helpful.

Comment: I tried it but it is giving me duplicates , maybe show me an example ?

Comment: The link I posted shows numerous examples. Read the "Avoiding multiple instantiations" section, it sounds like you are “initializing” the `Random` variable in a loop, which has a high probability of returning the same numbers. Show what you have tried.

Comment: and the output is still giving duplicates, so any help on how to prevent it

Comment: I have edit it, can you please take a look now, for now im outputting to the console

Comment: If you don't want duplicates, then you will need to "remove" the randomly picked `Disctionary` item from `callingNumbers` list in each iteration of the loop. With such a small random range it is almost guaranteed to duplicate one or more.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like below. In my small tests, there were no duplicates in the group of five (5).

```
Dictionary<string, string> availableCallingNumbers = new Dictionary<string, string>(callingNumbers);
int index;
for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i) {
  index = random.Next(availableCallingNumbers.Count);
  KeyValuePair<string, string> pair = availableCallingNumbers.ElementAt(index);
  Console.WriteLine("key: " + pair.Key + ", value: " + pair.Value);
  availableCallingNumbers.Remove(pair.Key);
}
```

Comment: this is working for me, thank you